# How can I get data from the Form into my Query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to run a query if

Forms!txtLanguageInd = "Spanish"

and run another query if its not

Here is my SQL query

```
IIf(Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtLanguageInd = "Spanish", 
(SELECT UserList.Clerkid, IIf([LastName]=" Smith",[LastName] & [FirstName],[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]) AS FullName, UserList.Status, UserList.ActiveToday
FROM UserList
WHERE (((UserList.Status)="Clerk") AND ((UserList.ActiveToday)=True)) OR (((UserList.Status)="Drug Court") AND ((UserList.ActiveToday)=True)) AND SpanishPrompt=True
ORDER BY IIf([LastName]=" Smith",[LastName] & [FirstName],[LastName] & ", " & [FirstName]);),
(SELECT UserList.Clerkid, IIf([LastName]=" Smith",[LastName] & [FirstName],[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]) AS FullName, UserList.Status, UserList.ActiveToday
FROM UserList
WHERE (((UserList.Status)="Clerk") AND ((UserList.ActiveToday)=True)) OR (((UserList.Status)="Drug Court") AND ((UserList.ActiveToday)=True)) AND SpanishPrompt=False
ORDER BY IIf([LastName]=" Smith",[LastName] & [FirstName],[LastName] & ", " & [FirstName]);))
```

Comment: Is there an error when you try your query?

Comment: Invalid SQL statement; expected DELETE INSERT PROCEDURE SELECT OR UPDATE. Basically I want to check a Form value to see if it's Spanish before executing the query

Comment: Did you try adding `SELECT` to the beginning? e.g. `SELECT IIF ...`? That's another thing. You have `Iff`, rather than `IIF`

Comment: changed it to IIF and same result

Comment: And you added `SELECT IIF(Logic, Query, Query) FROM Table` ?

Comment: well a new error was produced. I know my Query is good because it runs by itself.. The new error is "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery request only one field"

Comment: I think `IIF` will only allow you to return one value from one column if used with a subquery. I would look into `SWITCH`.

Comment: bjones. Please try it and let me know.

Comment: As a side note, I wonder what the whole "Smith" business is about.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is substantial...

```
SELECT IIF(SomeVariable=1,"TrueValue","FalseValue")
```

cannot be used as

```
IIF(SomeVariable=1,(Execute one statement),(Execute another statment))
```

Your are mixing the concept of a conditional expression and of a conditional processing... The semicolons you've put at the end of both of your statements indicate this clearly...

And the error *return more than one field* points to the same. If your two statements would return just one scalar value, this might work, but - for sure! not with a full statement returning many fields...

Comment: how can I get a query to execute based on the value of Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtLanguageInd

Comment: @softwareisfun, Is this *pure ms-access* or is there another RDBMS as backend involved? Most common - especially if both `SELECT`s return the same set of columns - is a `UNION ALL` with a proper `WHERE`-clause in both statements. You might think about dynamic SQL or some kind of VBA / Procedure / ...

Comment: This is Pure Access. (the database is Split and is still an ACCDB file)

Comment: Hi @softwareisfun , is this still open? Do you need further help? If this issue is solved, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. As you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this outer `IIf` at all, just put the condition into the WHERE clause.

This should do what you want, but you should check the order of precedence of OR and AND in the WHERE clause, you probably want another set of parentheses around the two OR conditions.

```
SELECT UserList.Clerkid, IIf([LastName]=" Smith",[LastName] & [FirstName],[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]) AS FullName, 
       UserList.Status, UserList.ActiveToday
FROM UserList

WHERE ((UserList.Status="Clerk") AND (UserList.ActiveToday=True)) 
   OR ((UserList.Status="Drug Court") AND (UserList.ActiveToday=True))
   AND SpanishPrompt=(Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtLanguageInd = "Spanish")

ORDER BY IIf([LastName]=" Smith",[LastName] & [FirstName],[LastName] & ", " & [FirstName]);
```